# WSUS icon in start menu now only opens up to "Options" node

Tags: wsus

Perhaps I was stupid.  In the WSUS console, I right clicked on "Options" and selected "New Window from Here".  It didn't open the new window, it just removed everything but "Options".

Not at all what I wanted.  Close window. re-open from Start menu.  Nothing but "Options".  Ick.

I know how to run `mmc`, add the wsus plugin, and connect to my server, but it's getting old and selecting WSUS from the start menu was so much quicker.

Is there any way of returning my start menu's WSUS entry to it's former function?

Comment: How about selecting the same "New Window from Here" on the correct location?

Comment: @EsaJokinen, I can only get to the correct location via, the run mmc/add plugin/connect routine.  In the end, I can save a .msc file to my desktop.  I suppose that's mighty close to the solution I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset console settings, delete the WSUS application cache from `%APPDATA%\microsoft\mmc`.

Note that this will reset all console settings related to the view. Server settings will leave untouched.

Answer (score 1):

This caught me out today as I've never utilised MMC in this way. To get back to the console, you can use the "Window" menu item at the top.

You'll also notice that the MMC Snap-In is a Window within a Window - you can use the controls to minimise the one you're 'stuck' in to get back to the base console.